# How to include Dojo charting in titanium project

Tags: javascript, html, charts, dojo, titanium

I'm trying to include Dojo charts in a titanium project.

I've tried to load a webview with Dojo declarations and then load the webview in the app. But I can't make it working. I've included in my project a folder (libs_dojo) with:

- dojo.js
- domReady.js
- dojox/charting/Chart
- dojox/charting/plot2d/Lines
- dojox/charting/axis2d/Default

This is the simple html I'm using:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Chart</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="simplechart" style="width: 250px; height: 150px;"></div>
    <script src='libs_dojo/dojo.js' data-dojo-config="async:true"></script>
    <script>
        require([
            "libs_dojo/dojox/charting/Chart",
            "libs_dojo/dojox/charting/plot2d/Lines",
            "libs_dojo/dojox/charting/axis2d/Default",
            "libs_dojo/domReady!"
            ],
                function (Chart) {
                    var chart = new Chart("simplechart");
                    chart.addPlot("default", {type: "Lines"});
                    chart.addAxis("x");
                    chart.addAxis("y", {vertical: true});
                    chart.addSeries("Series 1", [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7]);
                    chart.render();
                });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I tried it, I found a lot of "Error loading xxx/libs_dojo/_base/lang.js or libs_dojo/_base/array.js..."

How does dojo require work? Can I do it otherwise? programmatically? Do you know what the problem could be?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be helpful: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/charting.html?highlight=charts 
and 
http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/charting/

The second one is a very good Tutorial.

Make sure you have load all scripts needed to run dojo. Have you downloaded the dojo.js? 
Otherwise you must load it like this :

```
src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.1/dojo/dojo.js">
```

Here's an Example from dojo :

```
require([
 // Require the basic 2d chart resource
"dojox/charting/Chart",

// Require the theme of our choosing
"dojox/charting/themes/Claro",

], function(Chart, theme){
    // ....
});
```

Regards, Miriam

Comment: Thanks, the second tutorial help me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You should not pick and choose JS files from dojo package the way you seem to be doing. Either go with Miriam's approach of linking through web (googleapi) or place the whole dojo directory in your lib and reference dojo.js before anything else (that is require statements). You may want to read the example in CDN usage section of [Hello Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/hello_dojo/)

Every JS in dojo has dependent JS - which it fetches asnchronously (you might want to read up about dojo's AMD). The error that you see is because of some of the dependent JS not being found.